# How many substrings can be formed from a string of length n? BUT THE SUBSTRINGS LENGTH ARE LIMITED

Tags: combinatorics

string = "abcd" I'm looking for the formula which gives all the possible substrings but the substrings are limited in length.

For example all possible substrings for "abcd" are   4*(4+1)/2 = 10
But here I'm looking for all the possible substrings which have a max length of 2,
the result is 7 but what is the formula ?

thanks a lot for your help

**EDIT:**
I'm interested of the number of substring possible, **in order**, with a max length of 2, for example
"abcd" => a, b, c, d, ab, bc, cd  => 7
"1111" => 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 11, 11  => 7

A comment from @lulu that makes my question more clear:
 *I believe the OP is requiring the substring to consist of consecutive elements of the string. Furthermore, judging from the answer to my question about 1111, the OP isn't interested in the string itself...just in its start and end location*

Comment: sure downvote but tell me why or say it's a duplicate, I haven't found a duplicate of this for now

Comment: This is not clear.  If your string is $1111$, how many substrings are there?

Comment: There are $4! = 24$ substrings of length $4$, so I do not understand what you are counting when you say that there are a total of only $10$ substrings of abcd.

Comment: Have you tried counting the number of length 2 substrings in "abc", "abcd", "abcde" etc and seeing if you notice a pattern? You may be able to come up with a formula from that :)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I believe they are counting them as "a", "b", "c", "d", "ab", "bc", "cd", "abc", "bcd", and "abcd" (that is letters have to remain in order not randomly selected from all letters in the string)

Comment: @lioness99a  In that case, the count is still wrong, as there are $2^4$ substrings of a sequence of four distinct letters.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I've listed all 10 possible substrings...

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  I believe the OP is requiring the substring to consist of consecutive elements of the string.  Furthermore, judging from the answer to my question about $1111$, the OP isn't interested in the string itself...just in its start and end locations.

Comment: yes you are right @lulu

Comment: If the question is just about the number of ways to specify the first and last members of a substring of defined length, I'd say the answer was (clearly) $n+(n-1)=2n-1$ as $n$ elements can be the start of a length $1$ substring and $n-1$ can be the start of a length $2$ substring.  But I am not sure I have the question right.

Comment: length 2 is an example I would like the general formula, length m for a string of length n

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect what lulu said in response to my comment.

Comment: Well, doesn't my comment make that clear?  If you had max length $m=3$, you'd have $n+(n-1)+(n-2)=3n-3$.

Comment: ok so to generalize we have mn-m ?

Comment: @lulu I think in your last comment you wanted to write 
$mn-(m-1)$ 
Am I right ?

Comment: No.  Try $m=4$.  I'll post something below.

Comment: hmm yes not working indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sum up the discussion in the comments: the reference to substrings is misleading as the OP is not interested in the characters that make up the substring, only in the possible locations of their first and last elements.  Thus, the question is asking "given two natural numbers $m≤n$, how many pairs $(i,j)$ are possible with $1≤i<j≤n$ and $j-i≤m$?"

Let $F(n,m)$ denote the desired answer.

Example:  for $m=2$, there are $n$ places that might be the first element of a length $1$ substring, and there are $n-1$ that might be the first element of a continuous length $2$ substring.  Thus $$F(n,2)=n+(n-1)=2n-1$$

In general, there are $n-(k-1)$ places that might be the start of a continuous length $k$ substring.  Thus the answer is $$F(n,m)=n+(n-1)+\cdots + (n-(m-1))=m\times n -\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} i=m\times n-T_{m-1}$$

Where $T_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ [Triangular Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).  Thus $$T_i=\frac {i(i+1)}2$$

Examples:

$$F(n,2)=2n-T_1=2n-1$$
$$F(4,4)=4\times 4-T_3=16-6=10$$

Answer (score 2):

For "abc" valid substrings of length $2$ or less are "a", "b", "c", "ab", "bc", so $5$

For "abcd" we have $7$, as noted in your question, for "abcde" we have $9$, and for "abcdef" we have $11$

From this pattern, we can guess that, for a string of length $m$, there will be $2m - 1$ substrings of length $2$ or less

If we want length $3$ or less, then for "abc", we have $6$, "abcd" we have $9$, for "abcde" we have $12$ and for "abcdef" we have $15$

Here we can guess that there will be $3m-3$ substrings of length $3$ or less in a string of length $m$

Similarly, for length $4$ or less, we have $4m-6$ substrings in a string of length $m$

So, we can see the first term is simply $nm$ and we consider the second term of each formula. We note that for a substring of length $1$, this term would be zero, and so we are looking at the sequence $0,1,3,6,\ldots$. We note that a formula for this sequence (found through [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pattern+0,1,3,6)) is $$\frac 12(n-1)n$$

Therefore, we propose that, for substrings of length $n$ or less in a string of length $m$, we have $$nm - \frac12(n-1)n$$

We can then check this by counting other strings and substrings

Comment: Note: you reversed the OP's notation.  In the original problem, $n$ is the length of the entire string and $m$ is the maximum length of the desired substrings, you switched those.  But my other objection still stands:  it doesn't suffice to point out that the first few examples match a well known sequence, you have to prove that the two sequences coincide.

Comment: yes, I'll validate you lulu because you wrote the answer first, I just had more difficulties to read it (I'm bad I know) but you had the same formula

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort, answer and great explanation

Comment: The OP didn't have a notation in the post, I'd like to hope my answer was still understandable! And @FrançoisRichard you don't have to accept answers because they were first, accept the one that helped you understand (not saying mine did, just a point to note as that then helps other people with the same problem as you)

Comment: your answer was great, @lulu helped to clarify the problem in the comment ,you both provided great answer